# Quick Volumes with Lines Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was given the following prompt with the graph[image]:

"Let $R$ be the region bounded above by the graph of $y=1-x^2$ and below by the graph of $y=x^2-1$, for $-1\le x\le1$, as shaded in the figure above. What is the volume of the solid generated when the region $R$ is revolved about the horizontal line $y=3$?"

I understand that the bounds of the integral that would solve for the volume would be from $-1$ to $1$, but I'm a bit confused about what the equation for the volume might look like here. I was thinking it might look something like the following: $\int((1-x^2+3)^2-(x^2-1+3)^2)$, but I'm not too sure. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of rotating around the line $y=3$, we translate everything $3$ units down and solve
$$\pi\int_{-1}^1 \left[\left(x^2-4\right)^2-\left(-x^2-2\right)^2\right]\,dx=16\pi$$

alternative [Pappus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pappus%27s_centroid_theorem)

Compute di area $A$ between the "blue" parabolas, $A=\frac83$  and multiply by the circumference $C=6\pi$ described by the centroid $O$ of the region $A$

$$V=(6\pi)\cdot \frac83=16\pi$$

---

$$...$$
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bad description has caused ambiguity.  The shaded area represents the area **below** $(1-x^2)$ and above $(x^2 - 1)$.  I'm going to assume that it is intended that the volume of solid rotated around the line $y = 3$ will have the shaded area as its cross-sectional area.

In general, the volume will be

$$\pi \times \int_{-1}^1 \{[R(x)]^2 - [r(x)]^2\}dx$$

where $R(x)$ represents the **outer radius** that extends from $y = 3$ down to $y = (x^2 - 1)$ and $r(x)$ represents the **inner radius** that extends from $y = 3$ down to $(1 - x^2).$

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguous wording, I'm not usually a fan of how the questions I'm given are worded, so would you call the equation that I gave correct? Looking at it now it seems like the only fix I might have to make is swapping the polynomial terms, but other than that I thought it was correct?

Comment: @joe it wasn't that the wording was ambiguous; it was that the wording was inaccurate.  The ambiguity was in choosing how to resolve the discrepancy.  I opted for giving priority to the shaded region.  The alternative resolution wouldn't make sense, since if you allow area **underneath** the shaded area, then the region is **bottomless**.

Comment: Ok, I think I'm understanding what you're saying, so the given equation that I had (I completely forgot to insert my bounds) wasn't correct?

Comment: @joe "...so the given equation that I had (I completely forgot to insert my bounds) wasn't correct?" Right.  The upper bound on the region is $(1 - x^2)$, which is always non-negative, for $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.  The lower bound on the region is $(x^2 - 1)$, which is always non-positive, for $-1 \leq x \leq 1.$